# extract text from <p>...</p> tag or directly from an HTML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML page that contains some filenames that i want to download from a webserver.
I need to read these filenames in order to create a list that will be passed to my web application that downloads the file from the server. These filenames have some extention.

I have digged about this topic but havn't fount anything except -

1. Regex cannt be used to parse HTML.
2. Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Is there no other way so that i can search for text that have pattern like filename.ext from an HTML file?

Sample HTML that contains filename -

```
 <p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom=:0in; margin-left:1.5in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-.25in;line-height:normal;mso-list:l1 level3 lfo8;tab-stops:list 1.5in'><![if !supportLists]> <span style=3D'font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><span style=3D'mso-list:Ignore'>1.<span style=3D'font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span></span></span><![endif]><span style=3D'font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"; mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>**13572_PostAccountingReport_2009-06-03.acc**<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

I cant use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) because I m not allowed to download and make use of any application or tool.

Cant this be achieved by anyother logic?

This is what i have done so far

```
string pageSource = "";
            string geturl = @"C:\Documents and Settings\NASD_Download.mht";
            WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(geturl);
            WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                pageSource.Replace("=", "");
            }
           var fileNames = from Match m in Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+.+[a-z]")
                          select m.Value;
            foreach (var s in fileNames)
                Response.Write(s);
```

Bcause of some "=" occuring in every file name i m not able to get the filename. how can I remove the occurrence of "=" in `pageSource string`

Thanks in advance

Akhil

Comment: I can't see file name in the sample... :(

Comment: 13572_PostAccountingReport_2009-06-03.acc

Comment: Where is `.ext` here?! it can be every extension? what are the rules?

Comment: .ext is just an example. I meant it could be anything abc.acc or abc.zip etc.

Comment: So it's impossible, have a good day sir, I just wasted my time writing an answer. :(

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for ur precious time... But did u wrote an ANSWER. I thought we call it a COMMENT.

Comment: I wrote an answer but didn't publish it because of your comment.

Comment: It would be better. Might help me out.!!! :/

Comment: So I did, I don't know how much helpful it can be, but good luck with it.

Comment: @gordon:Thanks a lot. 
I have already digged a lot about this topic. Is it really not possible. There must be some way.
Even if i use HTML agility pack or some other tool I dont need text inside evry <p>..</p> tags. I just need the file names.

Comment: You'll need to identify something that surrounds the text you wan't and that doesn't change between your examples. When you know that it's easier

Comment: @Onkelborg : thats a nice tip :) but I have already lost a lot of my time searching the same. Neverthless, Thanks :)

Comment: I updated my answer. But it's still impossible.

Comment: I would use HtmlAgilityPack to extract the text inside the paragraph and then a proper regex to extract the file name in that text. What do you think?

Comment: I m really sorry my friend but I am not not allowed to use the pack in my application. But this idea of yours was really fantastic and could certainly prove result oriented. I have to do background code in anycase to search the file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, knowing that `regex` aren't ideal to find values in HTML:

```
var files = [];
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
    var match = p[i].innerHTML.match(/\s(\S+\.ext)\s/)

    if (match)
        files.push(match[1]);
}
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BNEwG/)

Note:
Read the comments to the question.

If the extension can be anything, you can use this:

```
var files = [];
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
    var match = p[i].innerHTML.match(/\b(\S+\.\S+)\b/)
    console.log(match)
    if (match)
        files.push(match[1]);
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = files + "";
```

​
But this really really not reliable.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BNEwG/3/)

Comment: Well this helped me a lot buddy. But still not getting exactly what i want.
But yet learned a lot..... Thanks :)

Comment: @akhil. Just be aware it will fail because of stupid things like this: `<p> I hate him.Once I even told him... </p>`

Comment: :D hahaha i know it will. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11222645/1474528 Cant we figure out somthing from this answer???

Comment: @akhil. I have seen better answers than this, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* use regular expressions to extract stuff that *looks like* file names. Since, as you correctly point out, regular expressions do not *parse* HTML, you might get false positives, i.e., you might get results that *look like* file names but are not.

Let's take an example:

```
string html = @"<p class=3DMsoNormal ...etc...";

var fileNames = from Match m in Regex.Matches(html, @"\b[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]{3}\b") 
                select m.Value;

foreach (var s in fileNames)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This will return

```
1.5in
1.5in
7.0pt
13572_PostAccountingReport_2009-06-03.acc
```

You see, HTML stuff that *looks like* a file name will be returned. Of course, you could refine the regular expression (for example, replace `+` with `{3,}`, so that at least three characters are required for the part before the dot) so that the false positives in this example are filtered out. Still, it's always going to be an *approximate result*, not an exact one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I remove "=" from the string i m reading from the file?

Comment: @akhil: Use `pageSource = pageSource.Replace("=", "");`. Note the `pageSource = ...` in the beginning, which you are missing!

Comment: but what if i want to catch multiple macthes of the regex pattern. The code i wrote just return me the first occurence that matches and then terminates.

Answer (score 0):

It may be impossible to get file names using common pattern because of `1.5in` `-.25in` `7.0pt` and the likes, try to be more specific (if possible), like
`/[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+/gi` or
`/>[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+</gi` (markup included) or even
`/>\d+_PostAccountingReport_\d+-\d+-\d+\.[a-z]+</gi`